# How do I put a button on specific frame in flash cs4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

i am using actionscript 3.0 , i want to create a button in a specific frame. I've created a button on frame 1 that goes to a specific frame, for example frame 2.  this is the code i am using for the button.

```
button1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1);
function btn1(event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

then, on frame 2, i want to put another button that only visible or appear on frame 2 when you click the button on frame 1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its a bit hack and bash but by default have the button on frame 2  set as invisible         `buttonName.visible = false..`
Then add the following to your event handler

```
button1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1);
function btn1(event:MouseEvent):void{
**buttonName.visible = true;**
gotoAndStop(2);
}
```